# passport authentication: user undefined after login

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js

I am trying to authenticate user ,when i try to login user after successful verification using `req.logIn` but it doesn't worked

```
router.post('/login', function(req, res, next) {
    passport.authenticate('login',function (cb,data) {
       //user verfication success
       if(data){
          req.logIn({user:"shamon"},function(err,result){
              console.log("result",result,err)
              res.send('login success');
          });
       }
    })(req,res,next);
});
```

this `console.log("result",result,err)`  gives me `undefined,undefined`

when i log `req.user` after logged i got undefined error

**UPDATE**

```
var LocalStrategy    = require('passport-local').Strategy

module.exports = function(passport){

    passport.use('local',new LocalStrategy({
        usernameField: 'email',
        passwordField: 'password'
    },function (username,password,done) {
         console.log('inside passport');
         return done(null,true);
    }));



    passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
        done(null, user);
    });

    passport.deserializeUser(function(user, done) {
        done(null,user);
    });

}
```

Comment: what is strategy of passport ?

Comment: i am using local  strategy

Comment: passport.authenticate('local', function(err, user, info) {
    if (err) { return next(err); }
    if (!user) { return res.redirect('/login'); }
    req.logIn(user, function(err) {
      if (err) { return next(err); }
      return res.redirect('/users/' + user.username);
    });

Comment: the same  i am used here

Comment: passport.authenticate('local' not login

Comment: Still i have the same issue

Comment: Can you please paste your strategy configuration file here

Comment: updated my question please check it

Answer (score 0):

Just grab my implementation of password local-strategy. This is working for sure, but you will need to slightly modify it:

The strategy:

```
// Serialize
  passport.serializeUser(function (user, done) {
  done(null, user.id);
});
// Deserialize
passport.deserializeUser(function (id, done) {
  User.findById(id, function (err, user) {
      done(err, user);
  });
});


passport.use('local-login', new LocalStrategy({
    // by default, local strategy uses username and password, we will override with email
    usernameField : 'email',
    passwordField : 'password',
    passReqToCallback : true // allows us to pass back the entire request to the callback
},
function(req, email, password, done) { // callback with email and password from our form
    // find a user whose email is the same as the forms email
    // we are checking to see if the user trying to login already exists
    User.findOne({ 'local.email' :  email }, function(err, user) {
        // if there are any errors, return the error before anything else
        if (err)
            return done(err);
        // if no user is found, return the message
        if (!user)
            return done(null, false, req.flash('loginError', 'No such user found.')); // req.flash is the way to set flashdata using connect-flash
        // if the user is found but the password is wrong
        if (!user.validPassword(password))
            return done(null, false, req.flash('loginError', 'Oops! Wrong password.')); // create the loginMessage and save it to session as flashd

        // all is well, return successful user
        return done(null, user);
    });
  }
));
```

And the route:

```
router.post('/login', function(req, res, next) {
  passport.authenticate('local-login', function(err, user, info) {
  if (err) {
    return next(err);
  }
  if (!user) {
    return res.send({alert: req.flash('loginError')});
  }
  req.logIn(user, function(err) {
    if (err) {
      return next(err);
    }
    return res.send({redirect: '/'});
    });
  })(req, res, next);
});
```

Comment: How do you include strategy in app.js

Comment: As simple as `var passport = require('passport');`